# Why do multiple test files cause Django issues when running in parallel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am using django 4.1 on windows.
running my tests sequentially (python manage.py test) works fine.
but when I run my tests in parallel (python manage.py test --parallel) I get the following error

```
File "C:\Users\SomeGuy\miniconda3\envs\SomeProject\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\SomeGuy\miniconda3\envs\SomeProject\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SomeGuy\miniconda3\envs\SomeProject\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 109, in worker
    initializer(*initargs)
  File "C:\Users\SomeGuy\miniconda3\envs\SomeProject\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 420, in _init_worker
    process_setup(*process_setup_args)
TypeError: process_setup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I created a project and made a folder underneath the main app folder for my tests called "tests" next to manage.py

I have two test files

test_losing_hair.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase


class WhyTest(TestCase):


    def test_counting_scheme(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

and
test_rapidly.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class WontThisWorkTest(TestCase):


    def test_counting_scheme(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

What Am I doing wrong here?

I've noticed running it in parallel works if I choose one file or the other,
but both at the same time creates the error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a known bug for Django 4.1 according to this
[Ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33891)

Can you update your Django version to 4.2? or 4.1.X where X being the latest within 4.1 ?

Comment: Ok thanks. I am running this within a conda environment and the latest non conda-forge django is 4.1 so I will just sit tight for now.